# Android - how can i know where was the focus when i pressed a button?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, focus

I have a page in my app where I have a lot of EditTexts.

Actually it's a ListView, with rows containing EditTexts, so the number of EditTexts is dynamic.

Normally users fill EditTexts they want, then press a Save button and we are done.
My problem is, some user forgot to leave the 'last' EditText, they just press the Save button, and this last EditText won't be saved. Because I use OnFocusChangeListeners to validate.

I don't want to check (again) all the EditTexts when the Save button was pressed, so what can I do?

Can I get where was the focus when I pressed a button? And then I only validate this EditText, not all of them.

Comment: Can you use a text watcher to validate your edit texts?

Comment: Hmm, I never used TextWatchers earlier. As I see now, it is something like that 'online validation', I mean u don't need to left your EditText to validate. Thanks for this tip, u will get my up if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your button on click listener, you can use `getCurrentFocus()` to get the currently focused view. Then just check if its an `EditText` and validate it.

Comment: Oh, the magic getCurrentFocus()! :) More easier then the other, thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a TextWatcher to validate your EditTexts